# Incrementing a number in a string using sub

Tags: regex, r, gsub

There's a string with a (single) number somewhere in it. I want to increment the number by one. Simple, right? I wrote the following without giving it a second thought:

```
sub("([[:digit:]]+)", as.character(as.numeric("\\1")+1), string)
```

... and got an NA.

```
> sub("([[:digit:]]+)", as.character(as.numeric("\\1")+1), "x is 5")
[1] NA
Warning message:
In sub("([[:digit:]]+)", as.character(as.numeric("\\1") + 1), "x is 5") :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

Why doesn't it work? I know other ways of doing this, so I don't need a "solution". I want to understand why this method fails.

Comment: Can't work without a callback capability of the gsub function. The alternative is to rewrite the string in a loop using a global _search_.

Comment: Basically, the _substitute_ string part of gsub is being used as a template with backref'd regex variables, to be formatted by an _internal_ callback (usually not available). So, you can't really run code within this part of the function, even with evil eval (which know's nothing of the match).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is that the backreference is only evaluated during a match operation, and you cannot pass it to any function before that.

When you write `as.numeric("\\1")` the `as.numeric` function accepts a `\1` string (a backslash and a `1` char). Thus, the result is expected, `NA`.

This happens because there is no built-in backreference interpolation in R.

You may use a [*`gsubfn`*](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gsubfn/) package:

```
> library(gsubfn)
> s <- "x is 5"
> gsubfn("\\d+", function(x) as.numeric(x) + 1, s)
[1] "x is 6"
```

Comment: Ah, of course -- as.numeric is evaluated first. Thanks for the insight. (And thanks to AEF and Laurel for their answers too!)

Answer (score 2):

It does not work because the arguments of `sub` are evaluated before they are passed to the regex engine (which gets called by `.Internal`).

In particular, `as.numeric("\\1")` evaluates to `NA` ... after that you're doomed.

Answer (score 2):

It might be easier to think of it differently. You are getting the same error that you would get if you used:

```
print(as.numeric("\\1")+1)
```

Remember, the strings are passed to the function, where they are interpreted by the regex engine. The string `\\1` is never transformed to be `5`, since this calculation is done within the function.

Note that `\\1` is not something that works as a number. NA seems to be similar to null in other languages:

> NA... is a product of operation when you try to access something that is not there

From mpiktas' answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5686).

Comment: R also has `NaN`. `NA` and `NaN` are similar but not identical.

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks for the info! I don't know much R, but I'm willing to learn. NA seems to be more similar to null in some languages.